# Iterating over libraries and execute task in Ant

Tags: ant, loops, directory

I need to be able to execute a task for all sub-directories with a certain name in Ant.
For each sub-dir, I need to do an exec task

How can I do this ?  Examples I found use fileset for copy tasks, which I can't use with the exec task, or use a for loop which I can't get to work.

I also tried some Javascript, but I can't get the FSO to work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the Ant [`apply` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html).
The task iterates over the members of a fileset-like object,
and it can process a [`dirset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html) too.

Here's an example:

```
<!-- all directories directly under working dir -->
<dirset id="my.dirs" dir="." includes="*" />

<apply executable="ls">
    <arg value="-l" />
    <dirset refid="my.dirs" />
</apply>
```

Apply has similar attibutes as the one-shot `exec` task.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this (you need the [antcontrib for task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)):

```
<for param="file">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="${yourdirectory}"/>
  </path>
  <sequential>
    <!-- do the work you need to here -->   
    <echo>Filename === @{file}
  </sequential>
</for>
```

This reference taken from [here](http://marc.info/?l=ant-user&m=115895273002164).

Comment: How do I install antcontrib ? Last time I tried it did not work at all.

Comment: Also I need to be able to retrieve the subdir name and use it for the command, I need to execute.
For each subdir I need to execute jar -cvfM ${subdir}.jar *png *jpg *gif

Comment: @Dennis Dahl Christensen - For antcontrib install, check here: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/  Also, I would think you can just write some script which takes the @{file} as a parameter, and this script would do the work of parsing out the subdir name and making the jar call.  And you would just call that script from the ant excerpt above (e.g. where the "do the work you need to here" part is).